# Silex and twig vars with punctation

Tags: twig, silex

I'm using Silex and Twig, and are having trouble printing some vars with punctations inside Twig:

```
$app['gateway.name'];

{{ app.gateway.name }}
```

If I had just a single punctation it would work fine, but not multiple.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use square bracket notation in twig as well:

```
{{ app['gateway.name'] }}
```

See also: [The template variables section of the twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables).